# How to count characters in array after while loop

Tags: php, loops, count, character

Do u have any ideas how to count all characters in string `$chars` after while loop ?

```
$x = 0;
$b = 0;

while ($x++ < 10) {
  echo $chars = $item->zodziai[$b++];
  echo ' ';
}

echo strlen($chars);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the characters then count them

```
<?php 
$x = 0; $b = 0;
$char = ''; //define a variable to collect all the chars
while ($x++ < 10) {
   $char .= $item->zodziai[$b++]; //add to the char
   echo $chars = $item->zodziai[$b++]; echo ' ';
}
echo strlen($char); //then count all the array combined
?>
```

Comment: @JonasJovaisas, If my answer worked, please do not forget to accept it as working solution(Click the small tick sign on the left of my answer) or even vote. Thanks